# how to view an user uploaded excel file within my web page

Tags: javascript, excel

In my application I want the user to upload an excel file and then he should be able to view the contents of the excel file with the web page where he uploaded. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to form a Question, that will be answered. This is no Code-providing platform.

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe save the excel sheet as a csv file, then upload, read the contents and write it on to the page. More info here: [read csv file from a location and display as html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36104089/read-csv-file-from-a-location-and-display-as-html-table)