# Manipulating a CSV with an HTML forms

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

I have a CSV file in my PC.
I would love to write a code which will display me on a webapp a table from CSV in my folder and will have a submission form to add new records in this file.
I don't have a server and python installed, (Flask and Pyinstaller are not valid solutions).
is there any way I can have a program to do these taks?
Happy monday to all

I have tried Flask but it works only with python. If the user doesn't have a python installed then the task is not feasable.
I have tried HTML and JS. But it wants server in order to update CSV.

Comment: Please select appropriate tags for your question. Tags are used by topic experts to find questions they can help with. You tagged this [tag:flask] and then ruled Flash out as a solution, which makes explicitly asking for Flask exports to help more than a little silly.

Comment: @Quentin thank you so much for suggestion. I will take into account for the next time

Answer (score 0):

All of what you're asking can be created using HTML, CSS and JavaScript only.

The following code snippet does the following:

1. Provides a drag and drop area for a `.csv` file (adapted from [here](https://web.dev/read-files)).
2. In the `drop` event handler, the file's metadata is parsed and dispayed.
3. In the same `drop` event handler, the file's content is parsed and dispayed as an HTML `<table>` element.
4. A form with three `input` control elements are provided.
5. The Add Data button adds the values from the `input` controls into a newly created row, inserted as the last row in the `table` element.
6. The Download CSV button converts the content in the table into a CSV string and then downloads the CSV string as a `.csv` file in the local browser.

There are several posts on Stack Overflow that cover [parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293147/how-to-parse-csv-data), [rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36104089/read-csv-file-from-a-location-and-display-as-html-table) as an HTML table and then later [downloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547198/export-html-table-to-csv-using-vanilla-javascript) CSV data locally without a server. I did not recreate most functions but added the source of each function in code comments.

There are optimizations that can be made to the code but it's all listed here to show that what your original post requires can be done with HTML/CSS/JS.

**NOTE** I've added the HTML/CSS/JS solution as a code snippet because it's more neatly formatted than listing HTML/CSS/JS as a code sample. The drag and drop handler and the Download CSV will not work while the code is running in Stack Overflow's code snippet view.

Here are images of the HTML user interface and the downloaded `.csv` file in Excel.

[image]

[image]

```js
// --------------------------------------------------------------
// Define drop zone
// https://web.dev/read-files/#define-drop-zone 

const dropArea = document.getElementById('drop-area');

dropArea.addEventListener('dragover', (event) => {
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
  // Style the drag-and-drop as a "copy file" operation
  event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
});

dropArea.addEventListener('drop', (event) => {
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
  const fileList = event.dataTransfer.files;
  getMetadataForFileList(fileList);
  readCsvFile(fileList[0]);
});

// --------------------------------------------------------------
// Read file metadata
// https://web.dev/read-files/#read-metadata

function getMetadataForFileList(fileList) {
  let html = "";
  for (const file of fileList) {
    // Not supported in Safari for iOS.
    const name = file.name ? file.name : 'NOT SUPPORTED';
    // Not supported in Firefox for Android or Opera for Android.
    const type = file.type ? file.type : 'NOT SUPPORTED';
    // Unknown cross-browser support.
    const size = file.size ? file.size : 'NOT SUPPORTED';
    //console.log({ file, name, type, size });
    html += `<span>${name}</span><span>${type}</span><span>${size}</span>`;
  }
  document.querySelector("#metadata").innerHTML = html;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------
// Read file metadata
// https://web.dev/read-files/#read-content

function readCsvFile(file) {
  // Check if the file is an image.
  if (file.type && !file.type.startsWith('text/csv')) {
    console.log('File is not a comma separated (CSV) file.', file.type, file);
    return;
  }

  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
    parseDataIntoTable(event.target.result);
  });
  reader.readAsText(file);
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------
// Parse data into an HTML table
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/14991797/5535143

function parseDataIntoTable(data) {
  // Display the parsed data in the console for
  // debugging purposes only.
  const parsedData = parseCSV(data);
  console.log(parsedData);

  // https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Import-CSV-File-to-HTML-Table-using-JavaScript.aspx
  const table = document.createElement("table");
  const rows = data.split("\n");
  for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    const cells = rows[i].split(",");
    if (cells.length > 1) {
      const row = table.insertRow(-1);
      for (let j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
        const cell = row.insertCell(-1);
        cell.innerHTML = cells[j];
      }
    }
  }

  document.querySelector("#data-table-content").appendChild(table);
}

function parseCSV(str) {
  const arr = [];
  let quote = false; // 'true' means we're inside a quoted field

  // Iterate over each character, keep track of current row and column (of the returned array)
  for (let row = 0, col = 0, c = 0; c < str.length; c++) {
    let cc = str[c],
      nc = str[c + 1]; // Current character, next character
    arr[row] = arr[row] || []; // Create a new row if necessary
    arr[row][col] = arr[row][col] || ''; // Create a new column (start with empty string) if necessary

    // If the current character is a quotation mark, and we're inside a
    // quoted field, and the next character is also a quotation mark,
    // add a quotation mark to the current column and skip the next character
    if (cc == '"' && quote && nc == '"') {
      arr[row][col] += cc;
      ++c;
      continue;
    }

    // If it's just one quotation mark, begin/end quoted field
    if (cc == '"') {
      quote = !quote;
      continue;
    }

    // If it's a comma and we're not in a quoted field, move on to the next column
    if (cc == ',' && !quote) {
      ++col;
      continue;
    }

    // If it's a newline (CRLF) and we're not in a quoted field, skip the next character
    // and move on to the next row and move to column 0 of that new row
    if (cc == '\r' && nc == '\n' && !quote) {
      ++row;
      col = 0;
      ++c;
      continue;
    }

    // If it's a newline (LF or CR) and we're not in a quoted field,
    // move on to the next row and move to column 0 of that new row
    if (cc == '\n' && !quote) {
      ++row;
      col = 0;
      continue;
    }
    if (cc == '\r' && !quote) {
      ++row;
      col = 0;
      continue;
    }

    // Otherwise, append the current character to the current column
    arr[row][col] += cc;
  }
  return arr;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------
// Add data to table
// 

document.querySelector("#add-to-table").addEventListener("click", addRowToTable);

function addRowToTable() {
  const tableElem = document.querySelector("#data-table-content table");

  const tableBodyElem = tableElem.querySelector("tbody");
  const trLastElem = tableBodyElem.querySelector("tr:last-of-type");
  const trNewElem = trLastElem.cloneNode(true);

  trNewElem.querySelectorAll('td').forEach(el => {
    el.innerHTML = "";
  });

  trNewElem.querySelector("td:nth-of-type(1)").innerHTML =
    document.querySelector("#col-1").value;

  trNewElem.querySelector("td:nth-of-type(2)").innerHTML =
    document.querySelector("#col-2").value;

  trNewElem.querySelector("td:nth-of-type(3)").innerHTML =
    document.querySelector("#col-3").value;

  tableBodyElem.appendChild(trNewElem);

  // 'scrollIntoView()' over scrolls even with
  // 'overscroll-behavior: none;' set on the
  // '#data-table-content' element.
  // trNewElem.scrollIntoView();
  // Therefore, the method selected as the answer:
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270612/scroll-to-bottom-of-div
  document.querySelector("#data-table-content").scrollTop =
    document.querySelector("#data-table-content").scrollHeight;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------
// Download CSV data
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547198/export-html-table-to-csv-using-vanilla-javascript
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/56370447

document.querySelector("#save-as-csv").addEventListener("click", saveAsCSV);

function saveAsCSV() {
  const tableElem = document.querySelector("#data-table-content table");
  const csv_string = convertTableDataToCsv(tableElem);
  downloadCsv(csv_string, "table");
}

function convertTableDataToCsv(tableElem, separator = ',') {
  // Select rows from table element
  const rows = tableElem.querySelectorAll('tr');
  // Construct csv array
  const csv = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    const row = [];
    const cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll('td, th');
    for (let j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
      // Clean innertext to remove multiple spaces and jumpline (break csv)
      let data = cols[j].innerText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, '').replace(/(\s\s)/gm, ' ')
      // Escape double-quote with double-double-quote (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808511/properly-escape-a-double-quote-in-csv)
      data = data.replace(/"/g, '""');
      // Push escaped string
      row.push('"' + data + '"');
    }
    csv.push(row.join(separator));
  }
  return csv.join('\n');
}

function downloadCsv(csv_string, table_id) {
  const filename = 'export_' + table_id + '_' + new Date().toLocaleDateString() + '.csv';
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.style.display = 'none';
  link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
  link.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv_string));
  link.setAttribute('download', filename);
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

```css
#file-data-wrapper {
  --border-color: #cccccc;
}

#file-data-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80vh;
}

#file-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-rows: 3fr 2fr;
}

#drop-area {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px dashed var(--border-color);
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#metadata {
  padding: 1rem;
  display: grid;
  align-items: start;
  height: fit-content;
}

#data-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'table' 'form''controls';
  grid-template-rows: 3fr 1fr 1fr;
}

#data-table {
  grid-area: table;
  position: relative;
}

#add-data-form {
  grid-area: form;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;
}

#add-data-form input {
  height: 2rem;
}

#form-controls {
  grid-area: controls;
}

#data-table-content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  overscroll-behavior: none;
  border: 1px solid var(--border-color);
}

#data-table-content table tr:first-of-type {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#data-table-content table td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-right: 1px solid var(--border-color);
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--border-color);
}
```

```html
<div id="file-data-wrapper">
  <div id="file-container">
    <div id="drop-area"><span>Drop area</span></div>
    <div id="metadata"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="data-container">
    <div id="data-table">
      <div id="data-table-content"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="add-data-form">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Column 1" id="col-1" />
      <input type="text" placeholder="Column 2" id="col-2" />
      <input type="text" placeholder="Column 3" id="col-3" />
    </div>
    <span id="form-controls">
            <button id="add-to-table">Add Data</button>
            <button id="save-as-csv">Download CSV</button>
        </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Dave B thanks for your solution I will try it today although I have talked to many web developers they told me it's not a solution. P.s I don't know who downgraded your answer. Please if that person is reading the comment could you state why you consider this solution as not useful?

Comment: I rewrote the post and added a complete solution that includes all HTML, CSS and JavaScript to meet the scenario stated in your original post.